# Compute of Gaussian integral with complex method.

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that $\int_C \exp(-z^{2}) = 0 $ because $\exp(-z^{2})$ is Holomorphic function in this domain so from Cauchy Theorem we have 0.

Suppose we have the contour like this figure:

[image]

I need show that 
$I = \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x^{2}) = \sqrt{\pi} /2$

Sketch:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x^{2}) = - \int_0^{\pi/4}\exp(-R^{2}e^{2it})i R e^{it} - \lim_{R\mapsto \infty} \int_R^{0} e^{i\pi/4}exp(-(e^{i \pi/2})(R-t)^{2})dx$$

I need show that 
$|\int_0^{\pi/4}\exp(-R^{2}e^{2it})i R e^{it}| $ where $R\mapsto \infty$ this integrate is 0. 
Proof of this.

I have triangle inequality for integrals
$$|\int_0^{\pi/4}\exp(-R^{2}e^{2it})i R e^{it} dt|$$

$$\leq \int_0^{\pi/4}|\exp(-R^{2}e^{2it})i R e^{it} dt| = R\int_0^{\pi/4}|\exp(-R^{2}e^{2it}) dt| $$
$$ \leq R/2 \int_0^{\pi/2} |\exp(-R^{2}i\sin\alpha) d\alpha|$$

$$\leq R/2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \exp(-R^{2}i\sin\alpha) d\alpha \leq R/2 \int_0^{\pi/2} exp(-2R^{2} \alpha/\pi) d\alpha \leq \pi/4R(1-e^{-R^{2}}) = 0 $$
where $R\mapsto 0 $

$\lim_{R\mapsto \infty} \int_R^{0} e^{i\pi/4}\exp(-i(x)^{2})dx = e^{i\pi/4} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-(i^{1/2}x)^{2} dx$
$$m = i^{1/2}x \quad 
dm = i^{1/2}dx$$
$$
 e^{i\pi/4} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-(i^{1/2}x)^{2}) =  e^{i\pi/4}/i^{1/2} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-m^{2}) dm 
$$
but $i^{1/2} = e^{i\pi/4}$ so it's reduce to Gaussian integral

so the conclusion

We have 
0 = I + 0 + I it's contradiction

I have issue, where it is mistake?